# angular2 target specific router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an app that has a base router-outlet that is used as a base for the entire app.  then a child router-outlet that is used once a user is logged in to display any components loaded as a result of clicking on a navigation link clicked that is based in the base router-outlet.  I want to be able to target the child router-outlet when a navigation link is clicked in the base template.

When I click on a nav item in the base template, it loads the component in the base router-outlet.  That makes good sense to me.  I would like to know how I can click a nav item in the base template and have the desired component load in the child router outlet.

I can't find any information on targeting a named router-outlet like I could do in RC4 (I think it was RC4) when i used to be able to do something like:

```
[routerLink]="/childroute#secureRouterOutlet"
```

Here is a really simple plunker that mimics how things are currently setup: [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/YxidcgAJaNjlrQnINnmw?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know how I can click a nav item in the base template and have the desired component load in the child router outlet

You can achieve that by enabling nested routes, you will need to setup `children` property on `Routes`. Here is the [doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html).

Here is how it can be done, specific to your use case from plunkr.

On `src/app.ts` specify any components you want to add as children in your `Routes` configuration. For example, adding `Child2Component` as nested routes on `ChildComponent` will be like below

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', 
        component: HomeComponent 
    },
    { 
        path: 'child', 
        component: ChildComponent, 
        children : [
            { path: 'child2', component: Child2Component }  
        ]
    },
    { 
        path: 'home',      
        component: HomeComponent 
    }
];
```

On the navigation, you will need to add the link to `Child2Component` as below

```
<a [routerLink]="['/child', 'child2']">Go to Child - Child2</a>
```

Now, when you hit that link, `ChildComponent` will render `Child2Component` template inside `router-outlet` in `ChildComponent`

Here is working [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/jQbJ9E?p=preview)

Comment: My problem was that I was confusing auxiliary routes for child routes. router-outlets get filled with components while traversing the tree.  So the first path match will go in the first router-outlet, the child route match will go in the next router-outlet and so on.  

Auxilary routes are different.  When you have two router-outlets on the same page and you want to target a specific one then you can used the named router-outlet format of /path(routeroutletname:pathtocomponent).  

The Angular 2 Router v3 is incredibly powerful and a bit complicated to wrap your head around initially.

Comment: Good to know @JakeHova

Answer (score 0):

Please try write like this, hope it helps.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/childroute#secureRouterOutlet']">
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't look like that works either.  I named the router-outlet "secureRouterOutlet" and then changed the nav link to the way you have it and it didn't work.  I know that used to work in a previous RC release, but I can't get it to work anymore.